# ExtJS - preventing earlier dates in calendar component

Tags: extjs, calendar

Is it possible to prevent `previousButton` in `'Ext.calendar.panel.Panel'` from showing dates earlier than `today`?

In addition, `views` config allows selecting `firstDayOfWeek`, where 1 equals Monday:

```
    views: {
        week: {
            firstDayOfWeek: 1
        }
    }
```

But, is it possible to configure `week` view to start always from `today`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the min date is not implemented in the calendar.
To start week from today, you can use the following code:

```
views: {
    week: {
        firstDayOfWeek: (new Date()).getDay()
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Before I accept the answer let's wait a while to see if someone knows how to prevent navigating to past days. I was thinking maybe if listeners to these navigation buttons could be caught, like beforeclick, than maybe it could just ignore the event.

Answer (score 0):

This is update of my question upon the answer from @Arthur Rubens:

Let's say that for the sake of generalization, instead of `(new Date()).getDay()`, some more complex function is needed to be calculated (for example factorial of that number times that number to the power of five, and then mod 7). Obviously, some method must be written, like:

```
    initComponent: function () {
        this.firstDayOfWeek = this.getTheResult();    // <- this is not defined
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    getTheResult: function () {
        // some calculation...
        return result;
    }
```

However, that raises two problems:

*1)* `this.firstDayOfWeek` is not properly defined since `firstDayOfWeek` is not property of class, but it is within

```
views: {
    week: {
        firstDayOfWeek:
    }
},
```

So, how to address properly that specific property? In other words, can be this property associated with some method (in this case `getTheResult`)?

*2)* I don't know for what reason, but `initComponent` simply doesn't work with calendar class.

Comment: Try this.views = { week: {firstDayOfWeek: this.getTheResult() } };

Comment: I've tried. It doesn't work. I always get error when trying to add initComponent ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unselectable' of null
    at constructor.onRender```

Comment: Have you done it before this.callParent(arguments) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking me. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3baf

Comment: Are you using modern toolkit? That is why it does not work..

Comment: No, I updated the fiddle. I am using classic toolkit. Without initComponent it's working, but as soon as I add initComponent block it fails

Comment: Well this is maybe a stupid question, but should it work for modern or classic? I've noticed that calendar works when I use modern toolkit, but this.views = { week: {firstDayOfWeek: this.getTheResult() } }; doesn't work - it shows Sunday instead of Saturday.